# Integrating Karate with TFS pipeline

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, karate

Build and release system we use is TFS, soon migrating toe Azure Devops. I am trying to introduce an automation framework for contract tests with Karate. Can Karate be integrated with the build jobs in TFS as part of the CI pipeline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Karate](https://github.com/intuit/karate) is a java API test-automation tool that can be implemented using Maven or Gradle.
It can be used to run on any CI/CD pipeline using any repository management.
Team Foundation Server is both repository management and CD/CD pipeline tools.

Please refer the below Azure configuration for Maven or Gradle,

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/gradle?view=azure-devops](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/maven?view=azure-devops)
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/maven?view=azure-devops](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/gradle?view=azure-devops)

Let us know if there are any configuration issue you are facing while downloading the karate library from azure.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Azure AD has a maven extension.

Following YML for reference

```
steps:
- task: Maven@3
  displayName: 'API Automated test against $(Environment)'
  inputs:
    mavenPomFile: Tests/APITest/pom.xml
    goals: 'clean test -DargLine="-Dkarate.env=$(Environment)"'
    testResultsFiles: '**/APITest.*.xml'
```